# How to buffer items when another observable emits true, and release them on false

Tags: system.reactive

I have a source stream and usually want to emit items as they arrive. But there is another observable - let's call it the "gate". When the gate is closed, the source items should buffer and be released only when the gate is opened.

I've been able to write a function to do this but it seems more complicated than it needs to be. I had to use the `Observable.Create` method. I assume there is a way to accomplish my goal using just a few lines of more functional code using the `Delay` or `Buffer` methods but I can't figure out how. `Delay` seems especially promising but I can't figure out how to sometimes delay and sometimes allow everything through immediately (a zero delay). Likewise I thought I could use `Buffer` followed by `SelectMany`; when the gate is open I'd have buffers of length 1 and when the gate is closed I'd have longer ones, but again I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Here is what I've built that works with all my tests:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns every item in <paramref name="source"/> in the order it was emitted, but starts
/// caching/buffering items when <paramref name="delay"/> emits true, and releases them when
/// <paramref name="delay"/> emits false.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="delay">
/// Functions as "gate" to start and stop the emitting of items. The gate is opened when true
/// and closed when false. The gate is open by default.
/// </param>

public static IObservable<T> DelayWhile<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<bool> delay) =>
    Observable.Create<T>(obs =>
    {
        ImmutableList<T> buffer = ImmutableList<T>.Empty;
        bool isDelayed = false;
        var conditionSubscription =
            delay
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .Subscribe(i =>
            {
                isDelayed = i;
                if (isDelayed == false)
                {
                    foreach (var j in buffer)
                    {
                        obs.OnNext(j);
                    }
                    buffer = ImmutableList<T>.Empty;
                }
            });
        var sourceSubscription =
            source
            .Subscribe(i =>
            {
                if (isDelayed)
                {
                    buffer = buffer.Add(i);
                }
                else
                {
                    obs.OnNext(i);
                }
            });
        return new CompositeDisposable(sourceSubscription, conditionSubscription);
    });
```

Here is another option that passes the tests. It is pretty concise but does not use the Delay or Buffer methods; I need to do the delaying/buffering manually.

```
public static IObservable<T> DelayWhile<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<bool> delay) =>
    delay
    .StartWith(false)
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .CombineLatest(source, (d, i) => new { IsDelayed = d, Item = i })
    .Scan(
        seed: new { Items = ImmutableList<T>.Empty, IsDelayed = false },
        accumulator: (sum, next) => new
        {
            Items = (next.IsDelayed != sum.IsDelayed) ?
                    (next.IsDelayed ? sum.Items.Clear() : sum.Items) :
                    (sum.IsDelayed ? sum.Items.Add(next.Item) : sum.Items.Clear().Add(next.Item)),
            IsDelayed = next.IsDelayed
        })
    .Where(i => !i.IsDelayed)
    .SelectMany(i => i.Items);
```

These are my tests:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("3-a 6-b 9-c", "1-f", "3-a 6-b 9-c", DisplayName = "Start with explicit no_delay, emit all future items")]
[DataRow("3-a 6-b 9-c", "1-f 2-f", "3-a 6-b 9-c", DisplayName = "Start with explicit no_delay+no_delay, emit all future items")]
[DataRow("3-a 6-b 9-c", "1-t", "", DisplayName = "Start with explicit delay, emit nothing")]
[DataRow("3-a 6-b 9-c", "1-t 2-t", "", DisplayName = "Start with explicit delay+delay, emit nothing")]
[DataRow("3-a 6-b 9-c", "5-t 10-f", "3-a 10-b 10-c", DisplayName = "When delay is removed, all cached items are emitted in order")]
[DataRow("3-a 6-b 9-c 12-d", "5-t 10-f", "3-a 10-b 10-c 12-d", DisplayName = "When delay is removed, all cached items are emitted in order")]
public void DelayWhile(string source, string isDelayed, string expectedOutput)
{
    (long time, string value) ParseEvent(string e)
    {
        var parts = e.Split('-');
        long time = long.Parse(parts[0]);
        string val = parts[1];
        return (time, val);
    }
    IEnumerable<(long time, string value)> ParseEvents(string s) => s.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(ParseEvent);
    var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    var sourceEvents = ParseEvents(source).Select(i => OnNext(i.time, i.value)).ToArray();
    var sourceStream = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(sourceEvents);
    var isDelayedEvents = ParseEvents(isDelayed).Select(i => OnNext(i.time, i.value == "t")).ToArray();
    var isDelayedStream = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(isDelayedEvents);
    var expected = ParseEvents(expectedOutput).Select(i => OnNext(i.time, i.value)).ToArray();
    var obs = scheduler.CreateObserver<string>();
    var result = sourceStream.DelayWhile(isDelayedStream);
    result.Subscribe(obs);
    scheduler.AdvanceTo(long.MaxValue);
    ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(expected, obs.Messages);
}

[TestMethod]
public void DelayWhile_SubscribeToSourceObservablesOnlyOnce()
{
    var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    var source = scheduler.CreateHotObservable<int>();
    var delay = scheduler.CreateHotObservable<bool>();

    // No subscriptions until subscribe
    var result = source.DelayWhile(delay);
    Assert.AreEqual(0, source.ActiveSubscriptions());
    Assert.AreEqual(0, delay.ActiveSubscriptions());

    // Subscribe once to each
    var obs = scheduler.CreateObserver<int>();
    var sub = result.Subscribe(obs);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, source.ActiveSubscriptions());
    Assert.AreEqual(1, delay.ActiveSubscriptions());

    // Dispose subscriptions when subscription is disposed
    sub.Dispose();
    Assert.AreEqual(0, source.ActiveSubscriptions());
    Assert.AreEqual(0, delay.ActiveSubscriptions());
}

[TestMethod]
public void DelayWhile_WhenSubscribeWithNoDelay_EmitCurrentValue()
{
    var source = new BehaviorSubject<int>(1);
    var emittedValues = new List<int>();
    source.DelayWhile(Observable.Return(false)).Subscribe(i => emittedValues.Add(i));
    Assert.AreEqual(1, emittedValues.Single());
}

// Subscription timing issue?
[TestMethod]
public void DelayWhile_WhenSubscribeWithDelay_EmitNothing()
{
    var source = new BehaviorSubject<int>(1);
    var emittedValues = new List<int>();
    source.DelayWhile(Observable.Return(true)).Subscribe(i => emittedValues.Add(i));
    Assert.AreEqual(0, emittedValues.Count);
}

[TestMethod]
public void DelayWhile_CoreScenario()
{
    var source = new BehaviorSubject<int>(1);
    var delay = new BehaviorSubject<bool>(false);
    var emittedValues = new List<int>();

    // Since no delay when subscribing, emit value
    source.DelayWhile(delay).Subscribe(i => emittedValues.Add(i));
    Assert.AreEqual(1, emittedValues.Single());

    // Turn on delay and buffer up a few; nothing emitted
    delay.OnNext(true);
    source.OnNext(2);
    source.OnNext(3);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, emittedValues.Single());

    // Turn off delay; should release the buffered items
    delay.OnNext(false);
    Assert.IsTrue(emittedValues.SequenceEqual(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: I forgot about the problems you'll run into with `Join` and `Join`-based operators (like `WithLatestFrom`) when having two cold observables. Needless to say, that criticism mentioned below about lack of transactions is more apparent than ever.

I would recommend this, which is more like my original solution but using the `Delay` overload. It passes all tests except `DelayWhile_WhenSubscribeWithDelay_EmitNothing`. To get around that, I would create an overload that would accept a starting default value:

```
public static IObservable<T> DelayWhile<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<bool> delay, bool isGateClosedToStart)
{
    return source.Publish(_source => delay
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .StartWith(isGateClosedToStart)
        .Publish(_delay => _delay
            .Select(isGateClosed => isGateClosed
                ? _source.TakeUntil(_delay).Delay(_ => _delay)
                : _source.TakeUntil(_delay)
            )
            .Merge()
        )
    );
}

public static IObservable<T> DelayWhile<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<bool> delay)
{
    return DelayWhile(source, delay, false);
}
```

---

**Old answer**:

I read a book recently criticizing Rx for not supporting transactions, and my first try at solving this would be a great example why:

```
public static IObservable<T> DelayWhile<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<bool> delay)
{
    return source.Publish(_source => delay
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .StartWith(false)
        .Publish(_delay => _delay
            .Select(isGateClosed => isGateClosed 
                ? _source.Buffer(_delay).SelectMany(l => l) 
                : _source)
            .Switch()
        )
    );
}
```

That *should* work, except there's too many things relying on the `delay` observable, and the subscription order matters: In this case the `Switch` switches before the `Buffer` ends, so nothing ends up coming out when the delay gate is closed.

This can be fixed as follows:

```
public static IObservable<T> DelayWhile<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<bool> delay)
{
    return source.Publish(_source => delay
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .StartWith(false)
        .Publish(_delay => _delay
            .Select(isGateClosed => isGateClosed 
                ? _source.TakeUntil(_delay).Buffer(_delay).SelectMany(l => l) 
                : _source.TakeUntil(_delay)
            )
            .Merge()
        )
    );
}
```

My next try passed all your tests, and uses your desired `Observable.Delay` overload as well:

```
public static IObservable<T> DelayWhile<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<bool> delay)
{
    return delay
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .StartWith(false)
        .Publish(_delay => source
            .Join(_delay,
                s => Observable.Empty<Unit>(),
                d => _delay,
                (item, isGateClosed) => isGateClosed 
                    ? Observable.Return(item).Delay(, _ => _delay) 
                    : Observable.Return(item)
            )
            .Merge()
    );
}
```

The `Join` could be reduced to a `WithLatestFrom` like this:

```
public static IObservable<T> DelayWhile<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<bool> delay)
{
    return delay
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .StartWith(false)
        .Publish(_delay => source
            .WithLatestFrom(_delay,
                (item, isGateClosed) => isGateClosed 
                    ? Observable.Return(item).Delay(_ => _delay) 
                    : Observable.Return(item)
            )
            .Merge()
    );
}
```

Comment: My favorite is the last one - I can understand it. That "recursive" thing - where _delay is used within the function passed to Publish - is what I struggled with as I was trying to use the Delay method. I didn't know you could pass a function to Publish and this is extremely useful. I didn't realize there was a version of Publish that returned an IObservable rather than an IConnectableObservable.

Comment: Hmm...your solution is not working with a really simple test case. My first couple solutions did work though. `[TestMethod]
    public void DelayWhile_SimpleTest()
    {
        var source = new BehaviorSubject<int>(1);
        var emittedValues = new List<int>();
        source.DelayWhile(Observable.Return(false)).Subscribe(i => emittedValues.Add(i));
        Assert.AreEqual(1, emittedValues.Single());
    }`

Comment: I added more test cases to my original post.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I think I'll stick with my original Observable.Create code. It is clear from looking at it that it will work. I don't totally understand why the other options (except your last suggestion) don't quite work are finicky or hang. Maybe it is those timing issues or that transaction issue you are talking about. Your last suggestion pretty much works but is kind of complicated to look at.

Comment: `Join` and `Join`-based operators rely on timing to join things. If you have two cold observables coughing up items upon subscription, then there's no timing to work with: just a race condition. Rx handles this by firing in subscription order, but principally the problem is bad design.

Answer (score 0):

A proposed concise answer. It looks like it should work but it doesn't pass all the tests.

```
public static IObservable<T> DelayWhile<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<bool> delay)
{
    source = source.Publish().RefCount();
    delay = delay.Publish().RefCount();
    var delayRemoved = delay.Where(i => i == false);
    var sourceWhenNoDelay = source.WithLatestFrom(delay.StartWith(false), (s, d) => d).Where(i => !i);
    return
        source
        .Buffer(bufferClosingSelector: () => delayRemoved.Merge(sourceWhenNoDelay))
        .SelectMany(i => i);
}
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't work; seems to hang when running the tests. So right now the only solution that works is my original LONG one with the Observable.Create.